# C# MemoryStream to text file not Completing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, text-files, memorystream

I'm having an issue with using a memory stream on a large text file function in C#. The output text file doesn't contain all the information, it's missing the last few lines of text that I wrote to it in streamwriter.

Many of the posts say to use stream.flush() and reset the stream to the beginning of the stream using stream.seek(0, seekOrigin.End), but neither seem to make a difference.

Here is the code:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var sb = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                Decimal[,] oparray = new decimal[477, 521];

                List<Rech_RCH_Result> result1;

                //RCH File Header
                sb.WriteLine("#MODFLOW2000 Recharge Package");
                sb.WriteLine("PARAMETER 0");
                sb.WriteLine("         1        50");

                for (int sp = 1; sp < 3; sp++)  //should be 209
                {
                    ObjectResult<Rech_RCH_Result> qryRCH = db.Rech_RCH(NRD, sp);

                    result1 = qryRCH.Select(p => new Rech_RCH_Result { M_Col = p.M_Col, M_row = p.M_row, Recharge = p.Recharge, StressPeriod = p.StressPeriod }).ToList();

                    //Stress Period Header for SP
                    sb.WriteLine("         1         1");
                    sb.WriteLine("        18     1.000(10e15.6)                   -1     RECHARGE");

                    //model row = 1 to 476, col = 1 to 520
                    foreach (Rech_RCH_Result s in result1)
                    {
                        oparray[s.M_row.Value, s.M_Col.Value] = s.Recharge;
                    }

                    for (int x = 1; x < 477; x++)
                    {
                        for (int y = 1; y <= 520; y += 10)
                        {
                            //write out values in chunks of 10
                            sb.WriteLine(string.Format("   {0:0.000000E+00}   {1:0.000000E+00}   {2:0.000000E+00}   {3:0.000000E+00}   {4:0.000000E+00}   {5:0.000000E+00}   {6:0.000000E+00}   {7:0.000000E+00}   {8:0.000000E+00}   {9:0.000000E+00}", oparray[x, y], oparray[x, y + 1], oparray[x, y + 2], oparray[x, y + 3], oparray[x, y + 4], oparray[x, y + 5], oparray[x, y + 6], oparray[x, y + 7], oparray[x, y + 8], oparray[x, y + 9]));
                        }
                    }

                    Array.Clear(oparray, 0, oparray.Length);
                }

                stream.Flush();
                //Looks like the stream is not completing and missing a few lines.
                //stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);


                using (FileStream file = System.IO.File.Create(Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/RCHFiles/{0}.txt", filename))))
                {
                    stream.WriteTo(file);
                }

                //using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
                //{
                //    zip.AddEntry(filename + ".RCH", stream);
                //    zip.Save(Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/RCHFiles/{0}.zip", filename)));
                //}
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're flushing the `MemoryStream`, but not the `StreamWriter`. It's possible that that's buffering.

Call `sb.Flush()` instead of `stream.Flush()`. (Flushing a `MemoryStream` doesn't do anything anyway.)

Also note that you can use `MemoryStream.CopyTo` without rewinding, instead of `Stream.WriteTo`.

Comment: You could just move the `}` matching the `using (var sb = new StreamWriter(stream))` a few lines up, before the seek, and remove the `Flush` call. A `StreamWriter` will flush itself on disposal.

Comment: It was the `StreamWriter` that was buffering and that seems to fixed the issue, but using your suggestion, if I change to `stream.CopyTo` instead of `stream.WriteTo` and remove the `stream.Seek()` line to not rewind, I get an empty file. Am I missing something?